# How to search by URL using Sphinx?

Tags: php, sphinx, sphinxql

I have index in Sphinx. One of field in index is URL. And it contains for example next values:

```
(1) http://u24.ru/news/38417/v-centre-chelyabinska-muzhchina-popytalsya-pereplyt-reku?rss
(2) https://meduza.io/feature/2017/07/10/islamskoe-gosudarstvo-vybili-iz-mosula-chto-budet-dalshe
(3) https://stolica-s.su/sport/athletics/89078
```

How I try to search by url (part of code):

```
$query = $this->manager->makeQuery()
    ->select(['id'])
    ->from(['content']);

$url = str_replace(
    ['=', '&', '?', '-', '%'],
    [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
    'http://www.ruscur.ru/themes/0/00/70/7020.shtml?news/0/10/43/104359'
);
$url = $query->escapeMatch($url);
$query->match('url', $url);

var_dump($query->execute()->fetchAllAssoc()); // empty
```

Is any way to search with Sphinx without using fulltext searching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a hash of URL and store it, then compare by hash:

```
$query = $this->manager->makeQuery()
    ->select(['id'])
    ->from(['content'])
    ->where('hash', '=', Hasher::hash($url));
```

Hint for query builder: http://foolcode.github.io/SphinxQL-Query-Builder/

Comment: In case it not clear to use it in 'where' need to make it an **Attribute** - as opposed (or in addition!) to **Field**. Attributes can be filtered with where. (as well as ordered/grouped and retrieved). So can put the URL in a **String Attribute**. Optionally could hash it as noted here, (which would reduce storage requirements), but no real benefit for actual matching. String attributes can only do exact equality filtering, not more complicated like `LIKE` in mysql.

Comment: Thanks for good idea. As I see my approach works as I need. I had problem with inconsistency of data in index.